# Gorm RaiseErrorOnNotFound not working as expected

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need gorm.ErrRecordNotFound to be returned in err variable when no records exists in database, but nil err is coming though there are no records in database.

```
func (r *MatchesRepository) GetLeagueIds(ctx context.Context, userID int) ([]int, error) {
    var leagueIDs []int
    var err error
    r.Get(ctx).Model(&model.Match{}).Statement.RaiseErrorOnNotFound = true
    err = r.Get(ctx).Model(&model.Match{}).
        Where(map[string]interface{}{"uid": userID}).Select("league_id").Find(&leagueIDs).Error
        fmt.Println("--gorm error---",err)  // printing nil
    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
            return leagueIDs, errors.New("Record not found")
        }
        return leagueIDs, err
    }
    return leagueIDs, nil
}
```

Couldn't find much details in Gorm documentation.Any other way to make this working ?

Comment: did you try with SQL logging.? 
` db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
   Logger:      logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
   PrepareStmt: true,
  })
`

Comment: Yes, Executed the printed query in my database also ,returns nothing. Query is SELECT "league_id" FROM "matches" WHERE "uid" = 4 AND "matches"."deleted_at" IS NULL
--gorm error--- <nil> @Netro